# Connecting Sqlite Database from navicat to android program

Tags: android

I have created my database in NAVICAT FOR SQLITE, now i want that database to be connected with my android Application.
I have surfed many webs but didn't found anything as a solution to my problem.
i don't know what will be the exact code for it?

However an additional feature i have to overcome is to handle some events like, if I update something in my Application, it should also be updated in my database which is currently in my desktop application.

I think it needs a WiFi connection for it?

Can some one guide me regarding this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there's two options for ur problem..

1. keep that database in assets folder and after starting the application copy the db from assets into application package.. refer this http://iamvijayakumar.blogspot.in/.../copy-sqlite...
2. keep that database on ur internal storage or sd card.. and give the full path as database name.. it will work...

Recommended: use 1st option..